# images loaded onto texture appear completely white

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, textures, arkit

I am applying a texture to a primitive plane using ARKit and Unity like so,

```
IEnumerator loadSpriteImageFromUrl( string URL, ARPlaneAnchor anchor ){
    WWW www = new WWW(URL);
    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log("Download image on progress" + www.progress);
        yield return null;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        Debug.Log("Download failed");
    }
    else
    {
        GameObject clone = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Plane);
        clone.transform.position = UnityARMatrixOps.GetPosition (anchor.transform);
        clone.transform.rotation = UnityARMatrixOps.GetRotation (anchor.transform);
        clone.transform.localScale = new Vector3(anchor.extent.x * 0.1f ,anchor.extent.y * 0.1f ,anchor.extent.z * 0.1f );
        clone.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(anchor.center.x,anchor.center.y,-anchor.center.z);
        Texture2D texture =new Texture2D(128,128,TextureFormat.RGBA32,false);
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);
        MeshRenderer m = clone.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        m.material.mainTexture = texture;
    }
```

But the image applied as texture  is completely white with no colors. Can someone please point my mistake. I checked the lighting, there are no issues.

Comment: I used jpg and png. JPG is white and if it s a png - if the alpha is 0 it appears gray if it is 1 I get white

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_100.jpg I used this as a sample

Comment: I am using this with arkit .. In the editor I connected with arkit remote and If change the Default-Material to Mobile>VertexLit I can see the image else it is black .. If I build the app and run it the texture is just plain white. I call the function like so, StartCoroutine(loadSpriteImageFromUrl("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_100.jpg", arPlaneAnchor));

Comment: Built it for iOS, the problem is on iOS. Yes the image is supposed to go on the plane

Comment: It is https stackover has rewritten the url so you weren't able to see it